# VPN PPTP inacceptably slow

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vpn

I have a VPN speed problem in Ubuntu.

I use PPTP to connect to my company's server. First I connect to a Mikrotik RB750 router. Then a NAS server (NTFS) is available and I can see, open, edit or save everything what is there. There is no connection problem of any kind.

However, when I browse files on NAS and open them locally, responses are very slow. It takes a lot of time to switch to subfolder or back.

When I do exactly the same thing within Windows XP (on the same machine, PPTP, Mikrotik, NAS, browse folders) the responses are much quicker (like 10 or 20 times quicker).

I tried different file managers in Ubuntu, but with no succes. No matter what I use, browsing through folders on NAS is painstakingly slow.

I checked what connection speed do I get with on-line speedtests when connected through VPN PPTP to Mikrotik router. Ookla gives me only about ½ speed comparing to what I get when I try the exactly the same thing with Windows XP.

I am trying to solve this for a couple of months now, but no succes. Company suggests that I return to Windows, since the work with VPN in Ubuntu seems to be impossible.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Should probably consider that PPTP is BAD so your company should use something better ;)  (It's real easy to breach)

Comment: For something like that I should be pretty sure it really would significantly improve the speed. However, WindowsXP works great with PPTP, so what's the problem with Ubuntu? Bear in mind it is a speed, not a security problem.